# Imacro Auto Downloader (IF THEN)

Tags: javascript, java, imacros

Hi all her is a part of my code.

I Like to Download for over 20 Laptops the Driver from the Toshiba Side. So 20 * 3 + X Drivers so i write the Macro for it. IT works well but i need a little help to implement a IF Statement sometimes there are many Drivers so 10 per Site and sometimes there are no Drivers for the OS.

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACTDIALOG NO
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !DATASOURCE ToshibaTreiber1.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
'Windows 7 - 64 Bit - TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:dp.osId CONTENT=%30
'WINDOWS 8.1 64 Bit - TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:dp.osId CONTENT=%46
'WINDOWS 10 64  Bit - TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:dp.osId CONTENT=%61
'{{!COL1}}
URL GOTO=http://www.toshiba.de/support/laptops/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:smpToolForm ATTR=ID:serialNo CONTENT={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:smpToolForm ATTR=TXT:Start
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Treiber<SP>herunterladen
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:dp.osId CONTENT=%30
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:dp.countryId CONTENT=%41
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:downloadForm ATTR=ID:searchBtn
WAIT SECONDS=15
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{!COL2}} FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=NO
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Download
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2
```

What i like is

```
**IF TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Download 
THEN**
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{!COL2}} FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=NO
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Download
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
**NEXT STEP**
**IF TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2
THEN**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2
**NEXT STEP**
```

Comment: For this issue I suggest applying the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) in 'iMacros for Firefox'.

Comment: Thanks i now do it with JavaScript Interface.